# tomcat 7 64-bit on windows 2008 r2 shows *32 in task Manager

Tags: tomcat, taskmanager

I have windows 2008 R2 64-bit.  I have installed 64-bit Tomcat and using 64-bit JRE.  Everything looks like setup as 64-bit such as the Tomcat is installed in "C:\program files\", java jre is in C:\program files\ so tomcat should be running in 64-bit mode.  However, in Windows task manager tomcat7 has *32 next to it.  Does it mean tomcat is running as 32-bit service?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why it was running as 32-bit.  Even though I used installation / setup for tomcat, it installed the 32-bit tomcat7.exe instead of 64-bit.  It was installed in 64-bit program files folder.  In order to fix this, I dowloaded the 64-bit tomcat zip and replaced the content of the tomcat7\bin folder.  I restarted the tomcat service and looked at the task manager.  It was showing as 64-bit.